# Apache deny access to subdirectories

Tags: apache-http-server

my goal is to deny access to certain sub-directories. my localhost configuration allows overriding like that:

```
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I also have an .htaccess file in /var/www/ with contents:

```
    <Directory /var/www/*>
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Those rules above state access to everyone, but my server responds with internal error.
"cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | tail -n 10" gives:

```
    [Thu Feb 23 12:41:09 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here"
```

Why is that so ? Any links on extensive guides on this problem are also extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear. You must remove

```
<Directory> and </Directory>
```

from your .htaccess file. `.htaccess` is applied automatically for the directory you put it IN, so there should be NO need to reference `<Directory>` directives in your `.htaccess`. On top of that apache documentation clearly mentions that `<Directory>` directives have server config and virtual host scope (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) - meaning you can only put them into `httpd.conf` (ie. main config) and within the `<VirtualHost>` directives